# _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-cloumn": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to code a management system and I'm working on adding customer details to the database but when i run the code an error message appears

This is my code:

```
submit_btn = Button(root, text="Add Customer To Database", command = submit)
submit_btn.grid( column=0, columnspan=2,ipadx=100, padx=10, pady=10, row=6)
```

This error displays in command prompt:

_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-cloumn": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky

Comment: looks like you had a typo `-cloumn` but the code you added seem to have it fixed. is the code in question giving the above error?

Comment: yep, it was a typo. Thanks for helping anyways :D

Comment: @ThatRandomGuy You added `column`  to that button but, where is `row`. Maybe, you aren't having the issue for it. Cause, the error is looking like another issue.